# action create couldn't be found for PostsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following a rails tutorial and need some help to proceed further. Problem is, once I fill out the form which has a title,body fields and hit submit, it has to redirect to the show.html.erb page instead it throws an error.

**Error:** The action 'create' could not be found for PostsController

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get "/pages/about" => "pages#about"
  get "/pages/contact" => "pages#contact"

  get "/posts" => "posts#index"
  post "/posts" => "posts#create"

  get "/posts/show" => "posts#show", as: :show
  get "/posts/new" => "posts#new"


end
```

**posts_controller_tests.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    def index

    end

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        @post.save
        redirect_to show_path
    end

    def show

    end

    private 

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<h1>Create a new blog post</h1>

<div class="form">

<%= form_for Post.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title %>: <br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %> <br> <br>

    <%= f.label :body %>: <br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %> <br> <br>

    <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>

</div>
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add the form to the question, it will be helpful

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: Post a link to the tutorial if it's online. Might be helpful.

Comment: @SoorajChandu, mudasobwa: I've added the requested to the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @sagarpandya82: It's an Udemy course, please check the below link.
https://www.udemy.com/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-for-complete-beginners/learn/#/lecture/3929144

The problem occurred at Lec 32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: You are using `posts_controller_tests.rb` not `posts_controller.rb`. You are putting your controller code in test controller.

Try to move the code in `app/controllers/posts_controller.rb`:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
    redirect_to show_path
  end

  def show

  end

  private 

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `create` action always redirects you to the show action. It doesn't matter if your model was saved or not.

You have to check if the model was saved or not:

```
 def create
   @post = Post.new(post_params)

   if @post.save
     flash[:success] = 'Successfully saved'
     redirect_to @post
   else
     render 'new'
   end
 end
```

If it wasn't saved, it renders the new action again.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `routes.rb` to this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get "/pages/about" => "pages#about"
  get "/pages/contact" => "pages#contact"

  resources :posts
end
```

Moreover you should inherit your controller from `ActionController::Base`

so change first line of your controller to

`class PostsController < ActionController::Base`

and move the controller to `app/controllers/posts_controller.rb`